# Pandas Dataframe adding muliple empty row issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have test the code to add multiple empty row to Pandas DataFrame it worked.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["James", "White", "John"],
                   'rebounds': [7, 7, 8]})

for i in range(100):
    dft =  df.columns.values.tolist()
    s = pd.Series(dft)
    df.loc[len(df)] =s
print(len(df.index))
```

In my application I have this code, its adding 16 empty rows but it adds only 4 rows.

```
    print(f"Before adding {len(df3.index)}")
    dft =  df3.columns.values.tolist()
    s = pd.Series(dft)
    for i in range(16):
        df3.loc[len(df3)] =s

    print(f"After adding {len(df3.index)}")
```

Output

```
Before adding 221
After adding 225
```

why its not adding 16 empty rows in my application code? How to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend stepping through with a debugger. Then you'll be able to run the line in your for-loop one-at-a-time and compare against the dataframe and see what is being added when.

Comment: also, separate from the main question completely, but a common convention when you have a for-loop but you aren't using the thing you are looping over (like you have here where you don't use the `i` in the `for i in range()` is to instead do `for _ in range(16)`. This can make it clearer to anyone reading the code that you are never going to use / never going to call the `i` (which we have changed to `_`). it won't have any change on how the code runs, just one how someone reads it

Comment: @scotscotmcc thanks,  below answer helped me on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have duplicated indices. For example if you array has 221 rows but an indice 222, no row will be added.

A more robust method could be to [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
N = 4
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns,
                                 index=range(len(df), len(df)+N))
                ])
```

output:

```
    name rebounds
0  James        7
1  White        7
2   John        8
3    NaN      NaN
4    NaN      NaN
5    NaN      NaN
6    NaN      NaN
```